# What word to describe the feeling of someone when they get offended?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

When I get offended, usually there is some kind of odd feeling on my chest as if something is growing inside it, ossified, makes me shudder (not because of fear, but because of anger) and limp at the same time. I will give an example here:

> 'If there is one coward on this earth who is too effeminate to act it
> is you!' Said Anne. Feeling ___(past participle), suddenly he hit Anne in the face.

I wanted to use the word "ossify", but after some thoughts it sounds awkward and doesn't make sense. I need one verb to describe the states I've mentioned above.

Comment: Whatever the correct word is, it is not "ossified". In its figurative sense, it means to have become stiff and resistant to change over a long period of time. The change you're attempting to describe here happens quickly and isn't about resistance to change.

Comment: I think you've described the feeling better than any single word can. Consider, "*Feeling **her offence grow inside his chest**, suddenly he hit Anne in the face.*"

Comment: I don't think there's a word that encapsulates those physical experiences you talk about, but *affronted*, *insulted*, *mortified* and similar words are all viable options in the more general sense of 'offended'.

Comment: @gotube That sounds great. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: As an aside - I'm not so sure I'd equate 'effeminacy' with 'cowardice', especially in this day & age.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. It was just an example I could think of anyway. Sorry if that doesn't make sense. I'm more into the word I'm asking for.